# cv2.polylines(), variable color based on z coordinate

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, graphics, drawing

I am converting polylines to images and the cv2.polylines function seems as a good place to start. Minimal example:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = np.zeros((16, 16, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

pts = np.array([[2, 2], [14, 13]], np.int32)

color = 255

image = cv2.polylines(image, [pts], False, color, 1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(image, origin="lower")
plt.show()
```

Produce the following image:

[image]

What I am asking is if there is a way to encode the z coordinate of a polyline as the color of the image, i.e

```
pts = np.array([[2, 2, 10], [14, 13, 230]], np.int32)
```

Would then instead produce the image:

[image]

Does anyone know a way to do it with cv2 or in any other way without having to write the entire conversion from polyline to an image?

Jakob

Comment: no way. not in python with OpenCV. OpenCV and C++: `LineIterator`. OpenCV is for **computer vision, not drawing 3D graphics**

Comment: If you have a depth image, you could conceivably mask your lines with the depth, but not directly while drawing the poly line. Make a binary mask from the poly line, then composite (put) the depth information into the mask. Then use the mask to modulate the red poly line.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will have a go at it